# Сортировка usort c пустыми строками

Tags: php, сортировка

Есть массив событий, отсортированных по полю `date` в хронологическом порядке. У событий может быть заполнено поле с неточной датой - такие события нужно поднять в начало списка. Использую `usort`. Но у большинства событий неточная дата не заполнена и тут начинается неожиданное:

```
$item = array(
    array("date" => 1, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 2, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 3, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 4, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 5, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 6, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 7, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 8, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 9, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 10, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 11, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 12, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 13, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 14, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 15, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 16, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
    array("date" => 17, "date_fuzzy" => ""),
);

usort($item, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['date_fuzzy'] < $b['date_fuzzy']) {
        return 1;
    } else if($a['date_fuzzy'] > $b['date_fuzzy']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

for($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++) {
    print($item[$i]['date']." - ".$item[$i]['date_fuzzy']." <br />");
}
```

Этот код выводит выводит даты в таком порядке

```
1 -
10 -
16 -
15 -
14 -
13 -
12 -
11 -
9 -
2 -
8 -
7 -
6 -
5 -
4 -
3 -
17 -
```

Хотя я ожидаю, что хронологический порядок не будет ломаться. И он не ломается, если убрать хотя бы одно событие. Для шестнадцати событий работает, для семнадцати - нет.
Пробовал использовать `strnatcmp`внутри `usort` - не помогло. Почему так, как починить?

Comment: Какая у вас версия php?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша версия php меньше 8.0. В [документации usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) написано:

> Замечание:
>
> Если оба сравниваемых значения эквивалентны, они сохраняют свой
> первоначальный порядок. **До PHP 8.0.0 их относительный порядок в
> отсортированном массиве не был определён**.

Т.е изначально их порядок не сохранен. В таком случае есть два варианта решения проблемы. Либо перейти на php8+ либо написать собственную реализацию функции сортировки аля `usort`.

Comment: Спасибо! Много времени потратил на проверку кода, т.к. изначально думал, что ошибка в нём, а не в рнр. До чтения документации руки не дошли)

Answer (score 2):

```
usort($item, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['date_fuzzy'] < $b['date_fuzzy']) {
        return 1;
    } else if($a['date_fuzzy'] > $b['date_fuzzy']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        if($a['date'] < $b['date']) {
             return 1;
        } else if($a['date'] > $b['date']) {
             return -1;
        } else {
             return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Либо использовать собственную реализацию сортировки:

```
function mergesort(&$array, $cmp_function = 'strcmp') {
    // Arrays of size < 2 require no action.
    if (count($array) < 2) return;
    // Split the array in half
    $halfway = count($array) / 2;
    $array1 = array_slice($array, 0, $halfway);
    $array2 = array_slice($array, $halfway);
    // Recurse to sort the two halves
    mergesort($array1, $cmp_function);
    mergesort($array2, $cmp_function);
    // If all of $array1 is <= all of $array2, just append them.
    if (call_user_func($cmp_function, end($array1), $array2[0]) < 1) {
        $array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
        return;
    }
    // Merge the two sorted arrays into a single sorted array
    $array = array();
    $ptr1 = $ptr2 = 0;
    while ($ptr1 < count($array1) && $ptr2 < count($array2)) {
        if (call_user_func($cmp_function, $array1[$ptr1], $array2[$ptr2]) < 1) {
            $array[] = $array1[$ptr1++];
        }
        else {
            $array[] = $array2[$ptr2++];
        }
    }
    // Merge the remainder
    while ($ptr1 < count($array1)) $array[] = $array1[$ptr1++];
    while ($ptr2 < count($array2)) $array[] = $array2[$ptr2++];
    return;
}
```

[Источник](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php#38827)

И еще у вас очень неоптимальное условие цикла:

```
$c = count($item);
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    print($item[$i]['date']." - ".$item[$i]['date_fuzzy']." <br />");
}
```

В противном случае интерпретатор будет подсчитывать количество элементов в массиве каждую итерацию.

Comment: Это же дополнительная сортировка по полю `$item['date']` каким образом это не меняет хронологию? Если у автора исходный массив в первом элементе дата не 1 а 100?

Comment: Супер, ваш вариант с usort, похоже, то, что надо!

Comment: @ВадимАлександру в вопросе указано,что массив отсортирована по полю `date`.